# create a form in placeholder in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
StringBuilder str=new StringBuilder();
str.Append("<div style='font-style:oblique;font-size:24px;text-align:left;margin-bottom:25px;'>");
str.Append("Products");
str.Append("</div>");
str.Append("<div style='font-style:oblique;font-size:18px;text-align:right;margin-bottom:25px;'>");
str.Append("<asp:TextBox ID='txtSearch' runat='server'></asp:TextBox> &nbsp;&nbsp; <asp:Button ID='btbSearch' runat='server' Text='Search'/>");
str.Append("</div>");
str.Append("<table width='100%' border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>");
```

In the second `<div>`, I try to create a textbox and a button and add them in the placeholder. When I debug with browser console, I see them in html code but it cannot show in the browser, it just show the table on browser. Is there any example to work these cases?

Answer (score 3):

`<asp:` tags are entirely server side tags.  They will be translated by the ASP engine into plain HTML tags.

By writing those tags to the response directly you bypass the ASP engine's ability to refactor them into proper HTML.  When the browser gets them it doesn't know how to render them, so it just ignores them.

You should be creating the controls as objects, rather than as strings, for example:

```
TextBox txtSearch = new TextBox();
txtSearch.ID= "txtSearch";
placeHolder1.Controls.Add(txtSearch);

Button btbSearch = new Button();
btbSearch.ID = "btbSearch";
btbSearch.Text = "Search";
placeHolder1.Controls.Add(btbSearch);
```

Or, better yet, you could place that text in a markup file rather than using the code behind.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you are not generating ASPX page to render on server, but rather sending output of your StringBuilder to the browser. Since `asp:TextBox` and similar ASP.Net elements can't be rendered by browser you see nothing in a view (also nodes are present as they don't make HTML completely invalid).

You want to generate `<INPUT...>` elements instead of `asp:TextBox` to see output in browser.

Note: there are likely better way to achieve your goal (i.e. client side templates, or regular rendering in the view), but you need to spell your actual problem first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use code like this

```
var tableBody=""; // here you have to define the table body yourself

var form=
    new {
        method=@"get", // decide for your request method get/post
        action=@"http://www.google.com" // the page processes the request
    };

var html=@"
<div style='font-style: oblique; font-size: 24px; text-align: left; margin-bottom: 25px'>Products</div>

<div style='font-style: oblique; font-size: 18px; text-align: right; margin-bottom: 25px'>
    <form method='"+form.method+@"' action='"+form.action+@"'>
        <input id='txtSearch' name='txtSearch'>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type='button' id='btbSearch' text='Search' onclick='this.parentNode.submit();'>
    </form>
</div>

<table width='100%' border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>"+tableBody+@"
</table>
";
```

The fixed part code of html is not necessarily consist with `StringBuffer`. If you want to generate the html dynamically, consider to use LINQ.

What should be done yourself are in the comments of the code. Notice that the `txtSearch` is not only given an `id`, but also `name`.

Comment: The entire point of using ASP is so that you don't need to do stuff like this; it will do most of the tedious boilerplate work for you.

Comment: So what is the advantage that you get from directly generating the HTML instead of using ASP in this context?  What problem are you trying to solve that ASP can't?

Comment: @Servy: External server page visualization and componentization.